# How to decide which stepPattern to use in DTW algorithm

Tags: r, algorithm, image-processing, comparison

I'am a little bit confused on which stepPattern to use with DTW algorithm.

I have to admit that a month ago i didn't know the existence of that algorithm.

So the story starts with a specific type of images comparison. 
As you can see below, is the way i chose to extract the "time" series data from images.

[image]

The idea is to get the distances from all forks to the first fork as it sown. So for two different images you have two different arrays with distance values.
A key point of that idea is that the values of these two arrays are correspond to each other.

By that, i mean that the first value of both arrays is the distance from the second left fork to the first main fork (as sown in the image with number 1) and so on...

By having those values, i used DTW algorithm by using the [R package](http://dtw.r-forge.r-project.org/).

Here is where i want your opinion. I tried this in 2 ways:

A) Asymmetric

I used that, because as i understood from something i read that you can use the asymmetric stepPattern if you have corresponding values to check. To compare value 1 of the first image with the value 1 of the other image, value 2 of the first image with the value 2 of the other image and so on...

First i run this

```
dist = dtw(F,K1,keep=TRUE,step.pattern = asymmetric)
```

and then i changed it to that

```
dist = dtw(K1,F,keep=TRUE,step.pattern = asymmetric)
```

Those two different executions returned me different distance value (`dist$distance`). I didn't like that but as i understood latter that results must be expected because that method change only by the i value (x axis) (correct me if i'm wrong).

B) Symmetric1

After that i decide to run it with a different way where

```
dist = dtw(F,K1,keep=TRUE,step.pattern = symmetric1)
```

and

```
dist = dtw(K1,F,keep=TRUE,step.pattern = symmetric1)
```

returns the same distance value (`dist$distance`).

As you know, there are more than those stepPatterns. So based on what should i choose the stepPattern for my case ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is probably the `symmetric2` pattern, which has the following desirable characteristics:

1. it's well-known and commonly used
2. it's symmetric, a property you understandably appreciate
3. it's normalizable, so you'll be able to compare alignments of different lengths.

Other patterns will lack one or more of the above properties.